use env file + environment in docker-compose.yml
I am working on this docker compose file:
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./api/Dockerfile
    container_name: api
    ports:
      - "8911:8911"
    depends_on:
      - postgis
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:postgrespw@postgis:5432/ffy_dev
    entrypoint: /bin/sh -c "sleep 5 && bash serve-api.sh"

What I would expect it to do is that it first reads all the entries from .env file and then the environment variable. The issue I am having is that i need to change one single variable (DATABASE_URL) for this API service and this entry is also in the .env file. So what I need is to somehow overwrite the one in the .env file with another one.
This way here does not work. Is there a way for it?
EDIT: the api/Dockerfile


######################
FROM node:20-alpine3.19 as base
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /app

COPY api/package.json api/package.json
COPY web/package.json web/package.json
COPY package.json package.json
COPY packages packages
COPY yarn.lock yarn.lock
COPY redwood.toml .
COPY graphql.config.js .
COPY .env.defaults .
COPY .yarnrc.yml .yarnrc.yml
COPY .yarn/releases .yarn/releases
COPY .yarn/patches .yarn/patches

RUN yarn install



######################
FROM base as api_build

RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat

COPY api api
COPY scripts scripts
COPY packages packages

RUN yarn rw build api


######################
FROM node:20-alpine3.19 as api_with_minimal_dep
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /app

COPY api/package.json .
COPY packages packages
COPY .yarn/releases .yarn/releases
COPY .yarn/patches .yarn/patches
COPY yarn.lock .
COPY .yarnrc.yml .
RUN yarn install


######################
FROM node:20-alpine3.19
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /app

COPY .yarn/releases .yarn/releases
COPY .yarnrc.yml .
COPY graphql.config.js .
COPY redwood.toml .
COPY .env.defaults .

COPY --from=api_with_minimal_dep  /app/node_modules /app/node_modules
COPY --from=api_with_minimal_dep /app/package.json /app/
COPY --from=api_with_minimal_dep /app/yarn.lock /app/
COPY --from=api_build /app/node_modules/.prisma /app/node_modules/.prisma
COPY --from=api_build /app/api/dist /app/api/dist
COPY --from=api_build /app/api/db /app/api/db

COPY api/src/server.ts api/src/server.ts


COPY serve-api.sh .
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "serve-api.sh"]



Are you using that value in the Dockerfile as well?
Please share the content of the ./api/Dockerfile

@Ouss updated the question, added the Dockerfile. i cannot change the env file.

Are you seeing the value from the .env file, the environment: value, or something else?  How are you verifying this?  Is the .env file also present in the container (it doesn't seem to be); is there code reading that or the .env.defaults file that might be overwriting the other environment variable?  (Do you have a similar problem without Docker?)

i am verifying it by opening a shell in the container and echo the variable. its the one from the env file, not the one from environment: ....

is serve-api.sh sourcing .env.defaults? and .env.defaults contains DATABASE_URL similar to the one in .env?

I recreated your setup (with simplification). I cannot reproduce the same results you are having.

Please refer to the original documentation... the precedence rules are pretty clear:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/envvars-precedence/

its strange, but i can overwrite the env variable by starting docker-compose like this:
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:postgrespw@postgis:5432/ffy_dev" BYPASS_DATABASE_URL="postgres://postgres:postgrespw@postgis:5432/ffy_dev" docker-compose up -d api web
